# Sea fishing rod all rounder

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle, fishing-rods

I'm looking at getting into sea fishing, I used to do coarse fishing.

I'd like an all rounder rod to try pier fishing and maybe some beach casting or fishing from a sea wall.

What should I look for most, rod length? Casting weight? Etc. Seen one which is 9ft with casting weight of 200g.

I don't know what weights I need either, or how rod length and weight affect each-other.

Comment: Does "course fishing" = [Coarse fishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_fishing) "angling for freshwater fish which are traditionally considered undesirable as a food or game fish."

Comment: I've edited to expand the question regarding weights as I think they are related to each-other.

Answer (score 1):

For extremely similar purposes here in Florida I use a 7 ft. medium heavy rod with a spinning reel that can handle 12-30lb test line and lure weights in the 1/2 to 2oz range.

Use the same rods/reels when I go for catfish in my local rivers as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anything surf or pier fishing I would recommend at least a 9 ft pole for casting far. I'm a big fan of Shimano Terez rods.